# PHP fread timeout with blocking mode

Tags: php, sockets, timeout, blocking, fread

So the thing is simple. I want to know if there is a possibility to set a timeout to an fread call and being in blocking mode at the same time!

The code is:

```
public function read()
{
    ...

    $data = fread($this->stream, 2);

    ...
}
```

This function, (you can see the hole project [here](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/blob/master/src/Engine/AbstractSocketIO.php#L104)), uses fread many times, and I **cannot** change the behaviour and set the non-blocking mode like this:

```
stream_set_blocking($this->stream, false);
```

I tried without success:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php#example-4583

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php#example-4582

Thanks!